# Как предварительно загрузить изображения в RecyclerView Android?

Tags: android, изображения, binding, recyclerview

> Необходимо перед bind как - то грузить изображения, чтобы не было подтормаживания загрузки пр скроле

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Product product = Products.get(position);
        if (position < Products.size() - 2 ){
            Picasso.with(contexts).load(BitmapUrlHelper.getPictureUrl(contexts, Products.get(position + 1).getImage(), 80)) .fetch();
        }

        if (position > 0 ){
            Picasso.with(contexts).load(BitmapUrlHelper.getPictureUrl(contexts, Products.get(position - 1).getImage(), 80)) .fetch();
        }


        if (product.getImage_preview_android() == null){
           setBackground(product.getImage(), holder.background_view, true)
        }
        else
            setBackground(product.getImage_preview_android(), holder.background_view,false);


    }

private void setBackground(String imageUrl, ImageView background, boolean croped) {
    Picasso.with(contexts).setIndicatorsEnabled(false);
    if (croped)
        Picasso.with(contexts)
                .load(BitmapUrlHelper.getPictureUrl(contexts, imageUrl, 80)).centerInside().resize(((displayWidth) - 10), (Integer) ((displayHigh) / 5)).placeholder(R.drawable.cart)
            .into(background);
   // loadBackgroundImage(background,BitmapUrlHelper.getPictureUrl(contexts, imageUrl, 80),((displayWidth) - 10), (Integer) ((displayHigh) / 5));

    else {
        Picasso.with(contexts)
                .load(BitmapUrlHelper.getPictureUrl(contexts, imageUrl, 80)).fit()
                .into(background);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну а пикассо вообще умеет по ссылке из кэша доставать? И если да - то может надо как-то ему это явно указать?

Comment: умеет, только как ?

Comment: Ну, в документации, наверное, написано что-то на сей счёт...

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо добавить бланковую картинку `placeHolder`, с размерами подгружаемого изображения. Пробните так:

```
Picasso.with(contexts).load(BitmapUrlHelper.getPictureUrl(contexts, Products.get(position + 1).getImage(), 80)). .placeholder(R.drawable.image_place_holder)fetch();

image_place_holder - собсна свою картину только выбирете
```

Comment: Это увеличит скорость подгрузки ?

Comment: скорость - никак

Comment: просто picasso каждый раз почемуто берет загружает картинки из инета, хотя они есть в кэшэ.

Comment: В ваш код просто сложновато вникнуть, я думал проблема в дергании списка

Comment: Это просто вставка изображения в методе onBindViewHolder класса  RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>